# Scrapy getting errors with Proxies -- twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm pretty new to `scrapy` and I am trying to scrape some craigslist pages using some proxies but I am getting some errors as shown below. I tried the command `scrapy shell "https://craigslist.org"` and it seemed to work fine.

From my understanding, if I want to use proxies, I have to build custom `Downloader Middleware`. I have done so here:

```
class ProxyConnect(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.proxies = None
        with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "chisel", "downloaders", "resources", "config.json")) as config:
            proxies = json.load(config)
            self.proxies = proxies["proxies"]

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if "proxy" in request.meta:
            return
        proxy = random.choice(self.proxies)
        ip, port, username, password = proxy["ip"], proxy["port"], proxy["username"], proxy["password"]
        request.meta["proxy"] = "http://" + ip + ":" + port
        user_pass = username + ":" + password
        if user_pass:
            basic_auth = 'Basic ' + base64.encodestring(user_pass)
            request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = basic_auth
```

This is my project structure:

```
/chisel
    __init__.py
    pipelines.py
    items.py
    settings.py
    /downloaders
        __init__.py
        /downloader_middlewares
            __init__.py
        proxy_connect.py
        /resources
          config.json
    /spiders
        __init__.py
        craiglist_spider.py
        /spider_middlewares
            __init__.py
        /resources
          craigslist.json
scrapy.cfg
```

settings.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'chisel.downloaders.downloader_middlewares.proxy_connect.ProxyConnect': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110
}
```

I was able to test to see if my proxy is working with this command it and it worked and got a source page back

`curl -x 'http://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{IP}:{PORT}' -v "http://www.google.com/"`

Scrapy version

```
$ scrapy version -v
Scrapy    : 1.1.0
lxml      : 3.6.0.0
libxml2   : 2.9.2
Twisted   : 16.2.0
Python    : 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) - [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]
pyOpenSSL : 16.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016)
Platform  : Darwin-15.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
```

Error:

```
$ scrapy crawl craigslist
2016-06-04 01:44:14 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0 started (bot: chisel)
2016-06-04 01:44:14 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'chisel.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['chisel.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'chisel'}
2016-06-04 01:44:14 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2016-06-04 01:44:14 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'chisel.downloaders.downloader_middlewares.proxy_connect.ProxyConnect',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-06-04 01:44:14 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-06-04 01:44:14 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-06-04 01:44:14 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-06-04 01:44:14 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-06-04 01:44:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-06-04 01:44:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://geo.craigslist.org/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl23_read', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
2016-06-04 01:44:17 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://geo.craigslist.org/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl23_read', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
2016-06-04 01:44:18 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://geo.craigslist.org/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl23_read', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
2016-06-04 01:44:18 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://geo.craigslist.org/robots.txt>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl23_read', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl23_read', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
2016-06-04 01:44:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://geo.craigslist.org/iso/MD> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl23_read', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
2016-06-04 01:44:21 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://geo.craigslist.org/iso/MD> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl23_read', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
2016-06-04 01:44:24 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://geo.craigslist.org/iso/MD> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl23_read', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
2016-06-04 01:44:24 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://geo.craigslist.org/iso/MD>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl23_read', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
2016-06-04 01:44:24 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-06-04 01:44:24 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 6,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 6,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 1668,
 'downloader/request_count': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 4, 8, 44, 24, 329662),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 4, 8, 44, 14, 963452)}
2016-06-04 01:44:24 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this because of using `base64.encodestring` instead of `base64.b64encode`. This error seems to usually happen when using proxy from proxymesh.com
Reference: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1855

This is the working middleware.

```
import base64

class MeshProxy(object):
    # overwrite process request
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # Set the location of the proxy
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://fr.proxymesh.com:31280"

        # Use the following lines if your proxy requires authentication
        proxy_user_pass = "user:pass"
        # setup basic authentication for the proxy
        encoded_user_pass = base64.b64encode(proxy_user_pass)
        request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
```